# How to use drag and drop in IntelliJ for java swing

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ for java application development using swing . It is difficult to manage content using layout manager. So, is there is any facility to make drag and drop features like in visual studio for vb.net...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use IntelliJ's GUI designer

JetBrains website has some resources detailing how to use it:

- [Designing GUI. Major Steps](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/designing-gui-major-steps.html)
- [Creating and Opening Forms](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/creating-and-opening-forms.html)
- [GUI Designer Basics](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/gui-designer-basics.html)
- [Components of the GUI Designer](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/components-of-the-gui-designer.html)

There are also several walkthroughs available on YouTube

---

Here are a few screen shots showing how to launch/display the designer:

[image]
[image]

The designer:

[image]