# Designing GUI in Intellij IDEA is more complex than in NetBeans

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea

I saw that the only option to design GUI in Intellij IDEA is `JPanel` only, and also it is not as flexible as NetBeans because NetBeans allows me to drag to wherever I want, but in Intellij, I only can put at the fixed place.

Also, seems like there is no JFrame in Intellij? If anyone knows how to create `JFrame` with drag and drop function, please let me know

Comment: hi please check this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37772825/how-to-use-drag-and-drop-in-intellij-for-java-swing/37773316

Comment: FYI, I have removed the NetBeans tag since your question is only about Intellij IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "inteliJ makes me put it at a fixed place."

IntelIj gui designer uses swing, which uses layout managers to control where things are. It sounds like you just don't have a lot of experience writing swing gui programs.

You can put them wherever you want, but you have to understand layouts to do that.